# Why can lists not be used as dictionary keys?

Tags: python, dictionary

I would like to have a list that is a key in a dictionary, defined like that:

```
data = { 
  [24,48,96]: ["QN.FN.EQ", "OT.AR.LN", "BL.VL.TR"] 
}
```

This does not work... the error says because "list type is not hashable...".

Is there any workaround? In order to be able to get data from that dictionary like this:

```
data[[24,48,96]] # => ["QN.FN.EQ", "OT.AR.LN", "BL.VL.TR"]
```

The only solution that I have now is - to convert the list to a string and use strings as keys.

```
data = { 
  "24,48,96": ["QN.FN.EQ", "OT.AR.LN", "BL.VL.TR"] 
}
arr = [24,48,96]
print(data[','.join(map(str,arr))])
```

Comment: Keys should be immutable, lists are mutable by design. Use a tuple instead.

Comment: use a tuple `(24, 48, 96)` instead of a list.

Comment: That is not an array, that is a list. list objects are not hashable, by design. tuples are, though

Comment: It looks as though, maybe, you need a dictionary of int to string where, e.g. `my_dict[24] == "QN.FN.EQ"`.  Is this so?

Comment: @Scott No, I needed the `tuple`!

Comment: Dictionaries work by hashing (calculating a number) on the key and using that hash to decide where to store the key and value.  Hashes are almost always based on the contents of an object.  So if you put a list as a key it would be stored a particular location based on its contents.  Then if the list were mutated, the hash would change.  And if the hash is changed the dictionary will look in the wrong spot to retrieve the values you stored.  So that's why Python doesn't provide a `__hash__()` method for lists.

Comment: I have edited your question a little, `[24,48,96]` is a list, not an array. This is important because we also have `numpy` arrays, `bytearray` and `array.array` ... (I also added some timings to my answer.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a tuple as a dictionary key instead:

```
data = { 
    (24,48,96): ["QN.FN.EQ", "OT.AR.LN", "BL.VL.TR"] 
}

print data[(24,48,96)]
```

Comment: Nice one, absolutely what I need!

Answer (score 6):

I'm answering the question in the title of this post. :)

Because lists are mutable, dict keys need to be hashable, and hashing mutable objects is a bad idea because hash values *should* be computed on the basis of instance attributes.

**Example 1**: hashing a mutable object where the hash value is based on a mutable characteristic of the object.

```
>>> class stupidlist(list):
...     def __hash__(self):
...         return len(self)
... 
>>> stupid = stupidlist([1, 2, 3])
>>> d = {stupid: 0}
>>> stupid.append(4)
>>> stupid
[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> d
{[1, 2, 3, 4]: 0}
>>> stupid in d
False
>>> stupid in d.keys()
False
>>> stupid in list(d.keys())
True
```

After mutating `stupid`, it cannot be found in the dict any longer because the hash changed. Only a linear scan over the list of the dict's keys finds `stupid`.

**Example 2**: ... but why not just a constant hash value?

```
>>> class stupidlist2(list):
...     def __hash__(self):
...         return id(self)
... 
>>> stupidA = stupidlist2([1, 2, 3])
>>> stupidB = stupidlist2([1, 2, 3])
>>> 
>>> stupidA == stupidB
True
>>> stupidA in {stupidB: 0}
False
```

That's not a good idea as well because equal objects should hash identically such that you can find them in a `dict` or `set`.

**Example 3**: ... ok, what about constant hashes across all instances?!

```
>>> class stupidlist3(list):
...     def __hash__(self):
...         return 1
... 
>>> stupidC = stupidlist3([1, 2, 3])
>>> stupidD = stupidlist3([1, 2, 3])
>>> stupidE = stupidlist3([1, 2, 3, 4])
>>> 
>>> stupidC in {stupidD: 0}
True
>>> stupidC in {stupidE: 0}
False
>>> d = {stupidC: 0}
>>> stupidC.append(5)
>>> stupidC in d
True
```

Things seem to work as expected, but think about what's happening: when all instances of your class produce the same hash value, you will have a hash collision whenever there are more than two instances as keys in a `dict` or present in a `set`.

Finding the right instance with `d[key]` or `key in d` needs to perform as many equality checks as there are instances of `stupidlist3` in the dict's keys. At this point, the purpose of the dictionary - O(1) lookup - is completely defeated. This is demonstrated in the following timings (done with IPython).

**Some Timings**

```
>>> lists_list = [[i]  for i in range(1000)]
>>> stupidlists_set = {stupidlist3([i]) for i in range(1000)}
>>> tuples_set = {(i,) for i in range(1000)}
>>> l = [999]
>>> s = stupidlist3([999])
>>> t = (999,)
>>> 
>>> %timeit l in lists_list
25.5 µs ± 442 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
>>> %timeit s in stupidlists_set
38.5 µs ± 61.2 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
>>> %timeit t in tuples_set
77.6 ns ± 1.5 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)
```

As you can see, the membership test in our `stupidlists_set` is even slower than a linear scan over the whole `lists_list`, while you have the expected super fast lookup time (factor 500) in a set without loads of hash collisions.

---

TL; DR: you can use `tuple(yourlist)` as `dict` keys, because tuples are immutable and hashable.

Comment: Why did you delete it lately? I just was in the middle of reading, glad you recovered it.

Comment: @BladeMight I thought it might be overkill, but then I changed my mind. :)

Answer (score 1):

Why Python dictionary can't accept array as dict key?

Answer: Becuase array is a list in python which is **mutable**. Mutable things cant be used a dict keys in python. you can only use **immutable** things like string , or tuple as key.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you're allowed to use a mutable data type as a key in Python. It's why tuples work, but lists don't. Essentially, if you can change the data in-place, you can't use it as a key.